# Get LanguageLocaleKey based on timezone ID

Tags: datetime, timezone, locale, format, languagelocalekey

I have a custom object called Machine__c and i have a custom picklist field in it called Time_Zone__c. This Time_Zone__c field has the same picklist values as the Standard User object timezone field.

Based on this timezone field i am converting the datetime values to that particular timezone and i want to show the dates as per the standard salesforce date formats.

the date formats change based on the user locale. i want to utilize the same thing here.

please let me know if it is possible.

below is the code for converting the datetime to required timezone.

```
public static string getFormatedTZ( Datetime exOccr, string TZ) {
        String locale_formatted_date_time_value='';
        if(exOccr != null) {
          Map<String, String> mappedValues = new Map<String, String>(); 
          mappedValues = MapValues();
          String user_locale = UserInfo.getLocale();
          String datetime_format = 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a'; //default it to US format
          if(mappedValues.containsKey(user_locale)) { //if the map contains the correct datetime format
             datetime_format = mappedValues.get(user_locale); //grab the datetime format for the locale           
          }
          if(TZ != null){
            locale_formatted_date_time_value = exOccr.format(datetime_format,TZ.subString(TZ.lastIndexOf('(')+1, TZ.length()-1));
          }else{
            locale_formatted_date_time_value = exOccr.format();
          }
        }
        return locale_formatted_date_time_value; //return the string    

    }
```

Below is the MapValues map.

```
public static Map<String, String> MapValues() {
      Map<String, String> locale_map = new Map<String, String>(); //holds the locale to timedate formats

      locale_map.put('ar', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm');     // arabic
      locale_map.put('ar_AE', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Arabic (United Arab Emirates)  
      locale_map.put('ar_BH', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Arabic (Bahrain)
      locale_map.put('ar_JO', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Arabic (Jordan)  
      locale_map.put('ar_KW', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Arabic (Kuwait)
      locale_map.put('ar_LB', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Arabic (Lebanon)
      locale_map.put('ar_SA', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
      locale_map.put('bg_BG', 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm');    //  Bulgarian (Bulgaria)
      locale_map.put('ca', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');     // Catalan
      locale_map.put('ca_ES', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // Catalan (Spain)
      locale_map.put('ca_ES_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'); // Catalan (Spain, Euro)
      locale_map.put('cs', 'dd.M.yyyy HH:mm');      // Czech 
      locale_map.put('cs_CZ', 'dd.M.yyyy HH:mm');     // Czech (Czech Republic)
      locale_map.put('da', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');     // Danish 
      locale_map.put('da_DK', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');    //Danish (Denmark)
      locale_map.put('de', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');     //German 
      locale_map.put('de_AT', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    //German (Austria)
      locale_map.put('de_AT_EURO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'); //German (Austria, Euro)
      locale_map.put('de_CH', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // German (Switzerland)
      locale_map.put('de_DE', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // German (Germany) 
      locale_map.put('de_DE_EURO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'); // German (Germany, Euro)
      locale_map.put('de_LU', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // German (Luxembourg)
      locale_map.put('de_LU_EURO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'); // German (Luxembourg, Euro)
      locale_map.put('el_GR', 'dd/M/yyyy h:mm a');    //  Greek (Greece)
      locale_map.put('en_AU', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // English (Australia)
      locale_map.put('en_B', 'MM/d/yyyy h:mm a');
      locale_map.put('en_BM', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // English (Bermuda)
      locale_map.put('en_CA', 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a');   // English (Canada) 
      locale_map.put('en_GB', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // English (United Kingdom)
      locale_map.put('en_GH', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    //  English (Ghana)
      locale_map.put('en_ID', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    //  English (Indonesia)
      locale_map.put('en_IE', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // English (Ireland)
      locale_map.put('en_IE_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'); // English (Ireland, Euro)
      locale_map.put('en_IN', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // English (India)
      locale_map.put('en_NZ', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    //  English (New Zealand)
      locale_map.put('en_SG', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    //  English (Singapore)
      locale_map.put('en_US', 'M/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');     // English (United States)
      locale_map.put('en_ZA', 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a');    // English (South Africa)
    locale_map.put('en_PH', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');      // English (Philippines)
      locale_map.put('es', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');     //  Spanish 
      locale_map.put('es_AR', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // Spanish (Argentina)
      locale_map.put('es_BO', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Bolivia)
      locale_map.put('es_CL', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');    // Spanish (Chile)  
      locale_map.put('es_CO', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Colombia)
      locale_map.put('es_CR', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Costa Rica)
      locale_map.put('es_EC', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // Spanish (Ecuador)
      locale_map.put('es_ES', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // Spanish (Spain)
      locale_map.put('es_ES_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'); //  Spanish (Spain, Euro)
      locale_map.put('es_GT', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Guatemala)
      locale_map.put('es_HN', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Honduras)
      locale_map.put('es_MX', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Mexico)
      locale_map.put('es_PE', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Peru)
      locale_map.put('es_PR', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Puerto Rico)
      locale_map.put('es_PY', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Paraguay)
      locale_map.put('es_SV', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (El Salvador)
      locale_map.put('es_UY', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Uruguay)
      locale_map.put('es_VE', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');    // Spanish (Venezuela)
      locale_map.put('et_EE', 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm');     // Estonian (Estonia)
      locale_map.put('fi', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');        // Finnish 
      locale_map.put('fi_FI', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');     // Finnish (Finland)
      locale_map.put('fi_FI_EURO', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');    // Finnish (Finland, Euro)
      locale_map.put('fr', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');     // French 
      locale_map.put('fr_BE', 'dd/MM/yyyy H:mm');     // French (Belgium)
      locale_map.put('fr_CA', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');    // French (Canada)
      locale_map.put('fr_CH', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // French (Switzerland)
      locale_map.put('fr_FR', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // French (France)
      locale_map.put('fr_FR_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'); // French (France, Euro)
      locale_map.put('fr_LU', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // French (Luxembourg)
      locale_map.put('fr_MC', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // French (Monaco)
      locale_map.put('hr_HR', 'dd.MM.yyy HH:mm');       // Croatian (Croatia)
      locale_map.put('hu', 'yyyy.MM.dd. H:mm');     // Hungarian 
      locale_map.put('hy_AM', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');     // Armenian (Armenia)
      locale_map.put('is_IS', 'd.M.yyyy HH:mm');      // Icelandic (Iceland)
      locale_map.put('it', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm');     // Italian 
      locale_map.put('it_CH', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // Italian (Switzerland)
      locale_map.put('it_IT', 'dd/MM/yyyy H.mm');     // Italian (Italy)
      locale_map.put('iw', 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');     // Hebrew 
      locale_map.put('iw_IL', 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');    // Hebrew (Israel)
      locale_map.put('ja', 'yyyy/MM/dd H:mm');      // Japanese 
      locale_map.put('ja_JP', 'yyyy/MM/dd H:mm');     // Japanese (Japan)
      locale_map.put('kk_KZ', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');     // Kazakh (Kazakhstan)
      locale_map.put('km_KH', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');     // Khmer (Cambodia)
      locale_map.put('ko', 'yyyy. M. d a h:mm');      // Korean (North Korea)
      locale_map.put('ko_KR', 'yyyy. M. d a h:mm');   // Korean (South Korea)
      locale_map.put('lt_LT', 'yyyy.M.d HH.mm');      // Lithuanian (Lithuania)
      locale_map.put('lv_LV', 'yyyy.d.M HH:mm');      // Latvian (Latvia)
      locale_map.put('ms_MY', 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a');   // Malay (Malaysia)
      locale_map.put('nl', 'd-M-yyyy H:mm');        // Dutch 
      locale_map.put('nl_BE', 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm');      // Dutch (Belgium)
      locale_map.put('nl_NL', 'd-M-yyyy H:mm');     // Dutch (Netherlands)
      locale_map.put('nl_SR', 'd-M-yyyy H:mm');     // Dutch (Suriname)
      locale_map.put('no', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');     // Norwegian 
      locale_map.put('no_NO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // Norwegian (Norway) 
      locale_map.put('pl', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');     // Polish 
      locale_map.put('pt', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');     // Portuguese 
      locale_map.put('pt_AO', 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm');     // Portuguese (Angola)
      locale_map.put('pt_BR', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');    // Portuguese (Brazil)
      locale_map.put('pt_PT', 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm');     // Portuguese (Portugal)
      locale_map.put('ro_RO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');    // Romanian (Romania)
      locale_map.put('ru', 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm');      // Russian
        locale_map.put('ru_KZ', 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm');       // Russian (Kazakhstan)
        locale_map.put('ru_RU', 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm');       // Russian (Russia)
      locale_map.put('sk_SK', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');     // Slovak (Slovakia)
      locale_map.put('sl_SI', 'd.M.y H:mm');        // Slovenian (Slovenia)
      locale_map.put('sv', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');     // Swedish 
      locale_map.put('sv_SE', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');    // Swedish (Sweden)
      locale_map.put('th', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');       //Thai 
      locale_map.put('th_TH', 'd/M/yyyy, H:mm a');    // Thai (Thailand)
      locale_map.put('tr', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');     // Turkish
        locale_map.put('tr_TR', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');      //  Turkish (Turkey)
      locale_map.put('ur_PK', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');     // Urdu (Pakistan)
      locale_map.put('vi_VN', 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');    // Vietnamese (Vietnam)
      locale_map.put('zh', 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm');       // Chinese 
      locale_map.put('zh_CN', 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm');      // Chinese (China)
      locale_map.put('zh_HK', 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm');      // Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China)
      locale_map.put('zh_TW', 'yyyy/M/d a h:mm');     // Chinese (Taiwan)
      return locale_map; //return the map
    }
```

This method shows the datetime in the required timezone and in the userlocale date format. but is there a way to show the converted date in the dateformat corresponding to the timezone to which the datetime is converted.

Comment: is this in lightning? LWC or AURA?

Comment: @salesforce-sas Not in lightning. I am using back bone Js for UI. But these conversions i am handling it in controller itself and just displaying it in backbone Js UI